# Laravel "Wrong password" error message

Tags: php, laravel-5.4

I'm creating a login function in Laravel 5.4 and I want to show error message in the view when the password is incorrect. Also I have a custom message for account approval so it makes things a bit difficult for me. Meanwhile I put those messages together but is not very user-friendly. How can I separate them?

This is my controller:

```
public function login(Request $request)
{
    // validate the form data
    $this->validate($request, [
        'email' => 'required|email|exists:users,email',
        'password' => 'required|min:6'
    ]);

    // attempt to log
    if (Auth::attempt(['approve' => '1', 'email' => $request->email, 'password' => $request->password ], $request->remember)) {

        // if successful -> redirect forward
        return redirect()->intended(route('user.overview'));
    }

    // if unsuccessful -> redirect back
    return redirect()->back()->withInput($request->only('email', 'remember'))->withErrors([
        'approve' => 'Wrong password or this account not approved yet.',
    ]);
}
```

As result i want to replace `Wrong password or this account not approved yet` with two separate messages:

If password is wrong to show: `Password is wrong`
If account not approved show: `This account not approved yet`

Comment: You can use like: `\Session::flash('error', 'Wrong password or this account not approved yet');
                     return redirect()->back()->withInput()->withErrors($errors);` And then print the session message in the blade file!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can pass custom error messages for each validation rule, you can do this:

```
    public function login(Request $request)
    {
        //Error messages
        $messages = [
            "email.required" => "Email is required",
            "email.email" => "Email is not valid",
            "email.exists" => "Email doesn't exists",
            "password.required" => "Password is required",
            "password.min" => "Password must be at least 6 characters"
        ];
        
        // validate the form data
        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
                'email' => 'required|email|exists:users,email',
                'password' => 'required|min:6'
            ], $messages);
    
        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return back()->withErrors($validator)->withInput();
        } else {
            // attempt to log
            if (Auth::attempt(['approve' => '1', 'email' => $request->email, 'password' => $request->password ], $request->remember)) {
                // if successful -> redirect forward
                return redirect()->intended(route('user.overview'));
            }
    
            // if unsuccessful -> redirect back
            return redirect()->back()->withInput($request->only('email', 'remember'))->withErrors([
                'approve' => 'Wrong password or this account not approved yet.',
            ]);
        }
    }
```

Before this, you have to include Validator class:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
```

Comment: hmmm... interesting,  but where should i put message 'Wrong password' ?

Comment: When you validate Auth::attempt, if it fails you can add a message doing this:

$validator->getMessageBag()->add('password', 'Wrong password');

And return withErrors($validator) on your redirect()->back()

Answer (score 1):

Without writing a new custom login method we can easily handle a custom **wrong password** message with the Auth default login process.

Open **LoginController** from the location: `app/Http/Controllers/Auth/`

Include the **Request** class if not exit on top of the controller

`use Illuminate\Http\Request;`

Finally add below line of codes at the very bottom of your LoginController to process the response error with custom message

```
    /**
     * Get the failed login response instance.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse
     */
    protected function sendFailedLoginResponse(Request $request)
    {
        $errors = [$this->username() => trans('auth.failed')];
    
        // Load user from database
        $user = \App\User::where($this->username(), $request->{$this->username()})->first();
    
        if ($user && !\Hash::check($request->password, $user->password)) {
            $errors = ['password' => 'Wrong password'];
        }
    
        if ($request->expectsJson()) {
            return response()->json($errors, 422);
        }
    
        return redirect()->back()
            ->withInput($request->only($this->username(), 'remember'))
            ->withErrors($errors);
    }
```

Comment: `return redirect(route('login'))->with('error', 'Please enter correct login credentials' );` will help you. Thanks.

Comment: in blade view file `@if (session('error'))
    <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible show">
        {{ session('error') }}
        <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
    </div>
@endif`

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this:

```php
return Redirect::back()->withInput(Input::all());
```

If you're using [Form Request Validation](http://laravel.com/docs/5.4/validation#form-request-validation), this is exactly how Laravel will redirect you back with errors and the given input.

Excerpt from [`\Illuminate\Foundation\Validation\ValidatesRequests`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/ebd86d7d2ff4e34b24a0dd84d10bb77c13130222/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Validation/ValidatesRequests.php#L123-L125):

> ```
> return redirect()->to($this->getRedirectUrl())
>                     ->withInput($request->input())
>                     ->withErrors($errors, $this->errorBag());
> ```

**Controller:**

```
public function login(Request $request)
{
    // validate the form data
    $this->validate($request, [
        'email' => 'required|email|exists:users,email',
        'password' => 'required|min:6'
    ]);

    // attempt to log
    if (Auth::attempt(['approve' => '1', 'email' => $request->email, 'password' => $request->password ], $request->remember)) {

        // if successful -> redirect forward
        return redirect()->intended(route('user.overview'));
    }

    // if unsuccessful -> redirect back
    return Redirect::back()
            ->withInput()
            ->withErrors(
                [
                    'password' => 'Wrong Password',
                ],
                [
                    'approve' => 'Account not approved',
                ],
            );
}
```

Comment: Sorry maybe u miss understand me,  i want to show error when password is incorrect

Comment: Try to use  ` return redirect::back()->withInput()->withFlashMessage('Wrong password or this account not approved yet.');`

Comment: I want to separate: If the password does not match show: Wrong Password.  And if account not approved show: Account not approved.

Comment: @DmitryMalys For that, you can check separate `if` conditions and return separate flash messages!

Comment: Try this: `return Redirect::back()
            ->withInput()
            ->withErrors(
                [
                    'password' => 'Wrong Password',
                ],
    [
                    'approve' => 'Account not approved',
                ],
            );`