# Laravel Error Message if password does not match

Tags: laravel-5

I'm struggling to find an answer to this problem

If the login password is wrong I want to display an error message.

This is my login function

```
    public function postSignIn(Request $request)
{
  $this->validate($request, [
    'email' => 'required|exists:users',
    'password' => 'required'
  ]);

  if (Auth::attempt(['email' => $request['email'], 'password' => $request['password']])) {
      return redirect()->route('dashboard');
  }
  return redirect()->back();

}
```

I have tried these methods but they not working.

(doesnt allow login even if password is correct)

```
'password' => 'confirmed'
```

(doesnt show any errors if password is wrong)

```
'password' => 'same:password'
```

(doesnt allow login even if password is correct)

```
'password' => 'same:pass'
```

My email authentication is working fine. Just want to display an error if the password is wrong for the email entered. Also my login does already work I've tested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So technically this isn't the perfect answer. But it is an alternative fix which works pretty well.

I got the answer from here

[Laravel "Wrong password" error message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45475990/laravel-wrong-password-error-message)

I just addded onto my redirect.

From

```
return redirect()->back();
```

To

```
return redirect()->back()->withInput($request->only('email', 'remember'))->withErrors([
            'approve' => 'Wrong password or this account not approved yet.',
]);
```

And then you can adjust the error message however you please.